# Echo JavaScript result in PHP/HTML source code?

Tags: php, javascript, html

This might be a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best.

I have a page that will display some results from JavaScript (time (HH/MM/SS) to be exact).

I need to display the results of JavaScript which is shown on the page *in the source code* of that page when viewed from a browser, like Firefox right click -> `view source files`.

I was thinking about echoing the results but that seemed to be a wrong idea, as echoing will only show the results on the page, and not in the source code of the page.

EDIT:

Okay, if it is impossible to show the results of the JavaScript in the page source, then how does this site display the result of the current time, etc, in the page source? I.e. Wednesday, July 31, 2013, etc, etc can be viewed on the page and on the page source.

http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136

I am using Google Chrome to view the page source.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client side, so change will never affect the _original_ source. However, modern browsers can show you the modified source, including changes made via Javascript. Use Chrome's "Inspect element" functionality or the tools provided by your preferred browser.

Comment: `view source` in browsers tends to be the document exactly as it was sent by the server. If you've got javascript modifying the page dynamically, you'll need to use a DOM inspector to retrieve the "live" html.

Comment: PHP source code will also never be visible in the page (View page source).

Comment: The current time displayed in the source code is probably the time updated by an AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

You can't alter the source code that comes from server by the means of JavaScript. While javascript can manipulate DOM objects, the text you see when you click "view source" is exactly as it came from the server, and there is no way you could change that.

To view the changes done by your scripts, use Firebug or some similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the source code you see when you hit view source, is the response of the http request that was send. Javascript can not alter that source. Any change you would make to the source (DOM) would only be visible in a DOM inspector (ie. ctrl+j in chrome or F12 in IE).

What you want is simply not possible from the javascript side.